# pep8 not running. pydev ubuntu?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pep8

[image]I have been using LiClipse on my windows machine for python development and get warnings about code line lengths etc. I am currently trying to set up a similar environment on my Ubuntu machine. I have installed eclipse, the pydev plugin, and managed to get my workspace set up. I have the suggested code analysis settings (well I think I do), but pep8 does not seem to work as it did in my LiCplise IDE. Side note, so far the Ubuntu development experience is not what it has been betrayed to me over the years, would go as far as damn poor TBH!

Edit: Folders do have a "__init__.py" file.

Edit:  Additional image

[image]

Taking pops in the dark also played with PyLint settings, both active and inactive.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the pydev package explorer for that project? Do you have some error in your error log?

Comment: I am not sure this is what you are after but added a new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the directory with the sources is not a valid python module because the folder that has the `__init__.py` has spaces in it.

i.e.: `/project/section2` is valid whereas `/project/section 2` is not (and PyDev does not analyze files which are not valid python modules).

Comment: Spot on @FabioZadrozny! Cheers!